# MVC problem in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am newbie to this technology.I am trying to create one window with form.The Html code is:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Search Window With Ext JS 4</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-4.0.1/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4.0.1/ext-all.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4.0.1/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="searchwindow.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="SearchRegionPan.js"></script>
 </head>

<body id="hello">
 </body>
 </html>

searchwindow.js:

Ext.require(['*']);

Ext.onReady(function(){

Ext.QuickTips.init();

 var searchRegionPan = new SearchRegionPan();

 //*************** SEARCH TAB *******************  
 var searchTab = {    
 id : 'searchTab',   
 border : false,    
 items : [searchRegionPan],    
 title : 'Search'    
 };

//*********** SCHOOL INFO TAB ***************    
 var schoolInfo = {       
 id : 'schoolInfo',          
 autoScroll : true,         
 border : false,      
 title : 'School Info'       
 };

//***************** QUICK SEARCH TAB **********************           
 var quickSearchMainTab = {           
 layout : 'column',         
 xtype : 'panel',         
 border : false,         
 id : 'quickpanelID',         
title : 'Quick Search',            
bodyStyle : 'background:#f7fbfc;'              
 };

//****************** GET ROUTE *******************               
 var getRoute = {                  
 id : 'getRoute',       
 layout : 'fit',           
 border : false,            
 title : 'Get Route',                 
 style : 'padding-bottom:10px'                      
};

//******************* LAYERS **********************     
 var layerss = {              
 id : "tree",                      
 title : 'Layers',             
 xtype : "treepanel",            
 height : 290,                        
enableDD : true                 
 }; 

//****************** TABS IN SEARCH MAIN TAB *******************      
 var tabs = {               
 margins : '3 3 3 0',                    
 activeTab : 0,                     
 style : 'background:none; padding-top:10px',              
 plain : true,            
 xtype : 'tabpanel',           
 id : 'tabs',             
 frame : false,            
 border : false,                
 deferredRender : false,               
 items : [searchTab, schoolInfo, quickSearchMainTab, getRoute, layerss]             
 };

// **************** SEARCH MAIN TAB *************************
 var searchMainTab = {
 id : 'searchMainTab',
 layout : 'fit',
 border : false,
 title : 'Search Info',
 items : [tabs] 
}; 

// ****************** REPORTS *********************
 var reports = {
 id : 'reports',
 layout : 'fit',
 border : false,
 title : 'Reports'
 };

//********** searchTabs USED IN SEARCH WINDOW *********** 
searchTabs = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
 margin : '3 3 3 0',
 activeTab : 0,
 style : 'background:none',
 plain : true,
 id : 'searchTabs',
 width : 350,
 style : 'padding-top:10px',
 frame : false,
 items : [searchMainTab,reports],
 border : false 
});

// *************** SEARCH WINDOW *********************
 var searchWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
 title : 'Search Window',
 width : 400,
 height : 380,
 x : 100, //to display search window 100px from left
 y : 100, //to display search window 100px from top
 draggable : true,
 autoScroll : false,
 plain : true,
 id : 'searchMainWindow',
 layout : 'fit',
 border : true,
 resizable : false,
 shadow : false,
 frame : false,
 closeAction : 'hide',
 items : [searchTabs],
 renderTo : hello //used to render to html page
 });
 searchWin.show();
 }); 


SearchRegionPan.js:

Ext.require('*');

//************ SEARCH REGION PAN USED IN SEARCH TAB **********
 SearchRegionPan = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
 id : 'searchRegionPan',
 border : false, 
style : 'padding:5px 10px 0 10px ',
 items : [RegionCityDistForm],
 frame : false
 });

//********* REGIONCITYDISTFORM USED IN SEARCH TAB **************
 var RegionCityDistForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
 extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
 id : 'regioncitydistform',
 frame : true,
 border : true,
 height : 100,
 padding : '10px 20px 10px 10px',
 width : '100%',
 layout : 'anchor',
 fieldDefaults : {
 labelWidth : 140
 },
 items : [Region,City,District]
 });

//********** REGION DECLARATION ***************
 var Region = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField',{
 fieldLabel : 'Region',
 selectOnFocus : true,
 width : 330,
 allowBlank : false,
 editable : true,
 emptyText : 'Select a Region...',
 triggerAction : 'all',
 typeAhead : true
 });
 //********** CITY DECLARATION **************
 var City = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField',{
 fieldLabel : 'City',
 selectOnFocus : true,
 width : 330,
 allowBlank : false,
 editable : true,
 emptyText : 'Select a City...',
 triggerAction : 'all',
 typeAhead : true
 });

//************** DISTRICT DECLARATION ******************
 var District = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField',{
 fieldLabel : 'District',
 selectOnFocus : true,
 width : 330,
 allowBlank : false,
 editable : true,
 emptyText : 'Select a District...',
 triggerAction : 'all',
 typeAhead : true
 });
```

If i am trying to execute the above code snippet, i am facing two issues.The issues are:

1) uncaught exception: Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically. Missing required class: SearchRegionPan
 2) b is undefined

I am trying a lot to come out from this issues.But am not able to succeedd.Please if anyone knows where i went wrong or where i need to modify code to come out from this issue,help me.

Thanks in Advance,
ramu

Answer (score 1):

It is very important how you include your files. You have to pay attention that all definitions are initialized before you use them. In your specific case you should the script include order from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="searchwindow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SearchRegionPan.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="SearchRegionPan.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="searchwindow.js"></script>
```

This makes sure that the class SearchRegionPan gets created before you try to instantiate it.

<strike>It is very important that you never, ever use the `new` keyword when using the class system functionality, because this will omit the added functionality like constructors, inheritance, mixins and plugins.</strike> (See comments, however the Ext JS docs recommend to always use Ext.create).

Thus

```
var searchRegionPan = new SearchRegionPan();
```

will become

```
var searchRegionPan = Ext.create('SearchRegionPan');
```

and your class definition

```
SearchRegionPan = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
  id : 'searchRegionPan',
  border : false, 
  style : 'padding:5px 10px 0 10px ',
  items : [RegionCityDistForm],
  frame : false
});
```

will become

```
Ext.define('SearchRegionPan', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel'
  id : 'searchRegionPan',
  border : false, 
  style : 'padding:5px 10px 0 10px ',
  items : [RegionCityDistForm],
  frame : false
});
```

I recommend you to read the blog post ['Countdown to Ext JS 4: Dynamic Loading and New Class System'](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system/), which explains how the class system works in detail.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.But am facing an issue called this.constructor.apply is not a function. please let me know where i went wrong.

Comment: The problem is that you are using the `new` keyword. I updated the answer to go into more detail on this.

Comment: @Netzpirat: Your statement about `new` v/s `Ext.create` is not correct. Inheritance and mixins will work just fine with both. The only difference is that Ext.create will attempt to dynamically load the class if not available, but `new` will simply fail.

Comment: @Rene Saarsoo You are absolutely right, I re-read the class system guide and it mentions exactly what you've said. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 0):

And also its better to use the MVC framework for Extjs 4 this will help you alot when its comes to building your application or else you will need some application for minifying your application into one `app.min.js` file for final deployment of your application